# What would be the value of $P$ in this example? (2)

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

> A Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ has the following transition matrix:
>   $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
>  0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
>  0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
>  0.3&0.2&0.5
>  \end{bmatrix}$$
>   with initial distribution $\alpha = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)$.
>
> Find $P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1)$ .

**My solution:**

$P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_0 = 3, X_1 = 1)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$
$\Rightarrow P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_1 = 1, X_0 = 3)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$
$\Rightarrow P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{P(X_1 = 1| X_0 = 3)\cdot P(X_0=3)}{P(X_1 = 1)}$

Now,

- from $P$, we have $P(X_1=1|X_0=3) = 0.30$
- from $\alpha$, we have $P(X_0=3) = 0.50$, and
- from $\alpha P$, we have $P(X_1=1) = 0.17$

So,

$P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1) = \frac{0.30 \cdot 0.50}{0.17}  \approx  0.88$.

**I have two questions regarding this:**

1. although, I wrote, "*from $P$, we have $P(X_1=1|X_0=3) = 0.30$*", I have a simple confusion here. When the system is at state $X_0$, it has an initial distribution of $\alpha$. So, theoretically, shouldn't it change its state according to $\alpha$ rather than $P$? This is actually practically impossible as $\alpha$ is a $(1 \times 3)$ matrix and hence there would be no $\alpha_{(3,1)}$. But, the question remains.
2. is there any better/easier method than what I used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, what you did is correct. Given that the chain is at $X_0 = 3$ you are interested in the transition probability to the state $1$. $\alpha(i)$ defines $\mathbf{P}(X_0 = i)$. It does not specify how the chain changes states but rather how it spontaneously starts.
2. Your use of Bayes' theorem is the fastest way I can imagine for that particular problem.

Comment: Is  $P(X_1 = 1) =0.17$ or $0.20$?

Comment: I get $\alpha P = (0.17, 0.28, 0.55)$ so $P(X_1 = 1) = 0.17$.